# Strange behaviour of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im new to android developing.
Created recyclerview which lists items on activity,implemented clickable items,so when I click item it starts the new activity, where details of item will be displayed.

The problem is that sometimes(not always), frequently when I click first or last item in recyclerview(its only 1st and last,because other item clicks work correctly) it crashes the app,and doesnt move to another activity.Please help me,cause I dont know why it is happening.

Adapter or recyclerview:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private List<Ads> ads=new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
DataAdapter(Context context, List<Ads> ads) {
    this.mContext=context;
    this.ads = ads;
}
@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder mView = new ViewHolder(view);
    return mView;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
     Ads ad = ads.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(ad.GetImage1()).fit().into(holder.imageView);
    holder.nameView.setText(ad.GetName());
    holder.priceView.setText(ad.GetPrice());
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AdInfo.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos",position);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ads.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView nameView, priceView;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        priceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    }
}
```

An activity where list is filled:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_activity);
    allAds=new ArrayList<>();Init();
    view=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter=new DataAdapter(this,allAds);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent=new Intent(client_activity.this,create.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("session", MODE_PRIVATE);
    nameShow=(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    nameShow.setText(pref.getString("name",null));
    phoneShow=(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);
    phoneShow.setText(pref.getString("phone",null));

}

private void Init()
{
    DatabaseReference ads= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ads.child("Ads").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            allAds.clear();adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          for(DataSnapshot shot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
          {
              Ads ad=new Ads();
              ad.SetImage1(shot.child("image1").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetImage2(shot.child("image2").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetImage3(shot.child("image3").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetCity(shot.child("city").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetInfo(shot.child("info").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetCategory(shot.child("category").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetName(shot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetPhone(shot.child("phone").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetPrice(shot.child("price").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetId(shot.child("id").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetUid(shot.child("uid").getValue(String.class));
              ad.SetAuthorName(shot.child("authorName").getValue(String.class));
              allAds.add(ad);
          }

            findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
```

My LOG

```
03-24 15:42:00.597 14361-14361/com.example.madik.sogim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.madik.sogim, PID: 14361
                                                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                         at com.example.madik.sogim.ImageAdapter.instantiateItem(ImageAdapter.java:43)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1002)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1150)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2672)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2107)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1223)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1459)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1114)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6068)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

03-24 15:42:00.674 397-397/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/14361/oom_score_adj; errno=22
03-24 15:42:00.772 8619-15470/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:46.180 8619-15456/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:46.254 14770-14770/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.581 14774-14774/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.628 14776-14776/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.671 14778-14778/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.715 14780-14780/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.758 14782-14782/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.803 14784-14784/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.845 14786-14786/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.900 14788-14788/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.945 14790-14790/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:46.989 14792-14792/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.madik.sogim-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-24 15:42:47.383 14757-14805/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:50.414 14757-14816/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:50.829 14757-14819/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:50.865 14757-14818/com.example.madik.sogim E/Theme: Different package name.com.example.madik.sogim,com.google.android.gms
03-24 15:42:53.808 14757-14836/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:53.962 14757-14843/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:54.917 14757-14854/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:54.933 14757-14855/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:56.027 14757-14856/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:56.089 14757-14857/com.example.madik.sogim E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:42:56.101 14757-14757/com.example.madik.sogim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.madik.sogim, PID: 14757
                                                                         java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                             at com.example.madik.sogim.ImageAdapter.instantiateItem(ImageAdapter.java:43)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1002)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1150)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5963)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2672)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2107)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1223)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1459)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1114)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6068)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-24 15:42:56.137 397-397/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/14757/oom_score_adj; errno=22
03-24 15:42:56.225 8619-15469/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-24 15:43:37.980 14730-14730/? E/SimcardDataModel: provide unsupported slot id 1

Comment: post your crash log !!

Comment: Crash may be this line parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout); where is itemView?

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: do not call `setOnClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder` - do it inside `DataAdapter.ViewHolder` constructor for example

Comment: move your onclick listener code to onCreateViewHolder. And set it for mView

Comment: please post your "AdInfo" class code. it seems that the problem is there.

Answer (score -1):

You have override methods that are not useful for you also returning incorrect values.
Please remove below lines of code :-

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Lets try holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener to  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener